# OnClick ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have followed this tutorial
http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/
and like to add an on click for the listview.

now here is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1px"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);    
steden = new ArrayList<voorDeLijst>();
this.m_adapter = new StedenAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, steden);
setListAdapter(this.m_adapter);

ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.List);
lv.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
         AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(HelloAndroid.this);
         adb.setTitle("LVSelectedItemExample");
         adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = ");
         adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
         adb.show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
});
```

The thing is that I am a beginner and with the code above I get an error because It cannot locate the listview. So I can't attach a OnItemClick Listener to it.
but when I change `<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"` to `<ListView android:id="@+id/List"`
Then I can find the listview. but it gives an exception at the line: `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

So how do I attach an onClick/onItemClick to a Listview which has a custom adapter to bind objects to the listitems?

Comment: With findViewById(R.id.List) you look for the view with the ID "List". Thus, it has to be "@+id/List" or you have to change it in the code, too. Btw, there is a predefined ListActivity which might be more suitable for you! Please provide more error information for the exception at "setContentView(R.layout.main)" in the second case.

Comment: My class does extend ListActivity, but I don't know how to attach an onClick listener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, because my class extended the `ListActivity` I could do this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{ 
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    // Get the item that was clicked
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String keyword = o.toString();
    ...
}
```

I found it at http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=22

Comment: @jean +1 u're doing a great job with android :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `findViewById(android.R.id.list)`? Really though, if your activity is basically one big list view, then you should be using a `ListActivity` for your activity, and that has an accessor that gives you direct access to the `ListView`.

Comment: I tried that but then I have an uncaught exception on the setcontent method. I don't know how to debug that properly. I am also new to Eclipse. My class does extend the ListActivity `public class HelloAndroid extends ListActivity {` but I don't know how to bind a onclick listener.

Comment: Whenever you get an uncaught exception, you need to send the logcat. Type `adb logcat V` in a console right after the crash.

Comment: And if you have a ListActivity, call `getListView()` to get the ListView.